# is there constructor function in move programming language?

Tags: aptos, move-lang

Is there any kind of a `constructor` like function, which will run at the time of deployment in `move` programming language?

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for `init_module`. This function runs just when you publish your module.

An example:

```
fun init_module(sender: &signer) {
    aptos_framework::managed_coin::initialize<MoonCoin>(
        sender,
        b"Moon Coin",
        b"MOON",
        6,
        false,
    );
}
```

From [aptos-move/move-examples/moon_coin/sources/MoonCoin.move](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/a7afb36d78f0513a2af5cd241701259d369840a7/aptos-move/move-examples/moon_coin/sources/MoonCoin.move#L5) in aptos-core.

You can learn more about it here: https://aptos.dev/move/move-on-aptos/modules-on-aptos/.

Comment: is init_module specific to aptos or move in general?