# In Aptos how do you you call initialize a constructor when deploying the contract with Aptos CLI

Tags: blockchain, move, smartcontracts, aptos

I want to know what is the constructor function (that is called during deployment) in Aptos move contract and how initialize a string value on the contract level when calling it. How to achieve this and how do I call it with argument with the `aptos move publish` command?

Comment: JFYI, we'll probably close this as it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76367239/3846032.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `init_module`. This function runs automatically just when you publish your module.

An example:

```
fun init_module(sender: &signer) {
    aptos_framework::managed_coin::initialize<MoonCoin>(
        sender,
        b"Moon Coin",
        b"MOON",
        6,
        false,
    );
}
```

From [aptos-move/move-examples/moon_coin/sources/MoonCoin.move](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/a7afb36d78f0513a2af5cd241701259d369840a7/aptos-move/move-examples/moon_coin/sources/MoonCoin.move#L5) in aptos-core.

You can learn more about it here: https://aptos.dev/move/move-on-aptos/modules-on-aptos/.

From the answer to this previous Stack Overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76367239/3846032.

Comment: I want to pass an argument and initialize the contract with a string value in the constructor. Is the possible?

Comment: This is not possible unfortunately. You could define a custom method like `my_init_module` and then check that the caller is the deployer of the module and make sure it can only be called once.